# Why does angular keep showing false when input is touched?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular. I have set up the following code to see if an input field has been touched. However when i type on the input field. It doesn't change. Just keeps showing false.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be really appreciated it.

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-form name="myForm">

    <input type='text' name='address' ng-model="address" id='address'>

    <h1> {{myForm.address.$touched}}</h1>


</div>



<script>

    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

</script>
```

Comment: make sure you use angular version v1.30 and above

Comment: Have you tried "{{adress.$touched}}" yet, or maybe defining scope in your controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$touched` in AngularJS jargon doesn't mean "was the value changed". That's `$dirty`'s role.

`$touched` in AngularJS means that the field was blurred (that is, the field isn't selected anymore).

[See it in action at plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co/edit/VzKYbuIj19Gcfjsk4u9J?p=preview).